# How do I render a widget based on a condition in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget, render

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(MyApp.title),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: (()=>{
      if(!list){
        return Register();
      }
      else{
        return Homepage();
      }
    })
  );
```

My application fetches a list from local storage on init afterwards the next page to be rendered depends on whether the list is empty or not. Is there a way to determine which widget to render base on a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(MyApp.title),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: list.isEmpty ? Register() : Homepage()
  );
```

Comment: It worked, sorry for the dumb question. I'm pretty new to Dart it is nothing like Javascript

Comment: Its ok ! All the best !